# Use of phfqit package: doubt

Tags: math-mode, packages, font-encodings, apostrophe

This morning I have discovered this package named: [phfqit](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/phfqit/phfqit.pdf). At the page 4 there is, for example, an example

```
\Hmin‘\Big{\bigotimes_i A_i}[B]
```

with a character `‘`. I have tried to use `fontenc`, `inputenc`, `utf-8` packages but without success to have the correct output becasue the `‘` it is not recognized.

The minimal working example is:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{phfqit}
\begin{document}
\[\Hmin‘\Big{\bigotimes_i A_i}[B]\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: You have to use the backtick, not the apostrophe: `\` `

Comment: @egreg Hi, and thank your very much for your comment. Now I have tried but....I have: `Missing delimiter (. inserted). [\[\Hmin'\Big{\bigotimes_i A_i}]`. Please, can you try?

Comment: You still have a quote, not a backtick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct symbol is `` ` `` (the backtick). Most fonts render this as an open quote, and so does the font used for the package manual.

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{phfqit}
\begin{document}
\[\Hmin`\Big{\bigotimes_i A_i}[B]\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ah, I thought that backtick was `'`. Thank you very much for your answer.